# mod rewrite setup

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to setup a mod rewrite rule to change urls like:

http://www.site.com/play/4435

Into:

http://www.site.com/index.php?play=4435

Below is what I have but it is not quite right...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?play=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^play/([^/]*)$ /index.php?play=$1 [L]
```

That should change http://www.site.com/play/4435 into http://www.site.com/index.php?play=4435

Hope that helps :)

Comment: They probably don't want `play` hardcoded into the rules there.

Comment: If everything works but images & flash then you will probably need to change the way you are linking to the resources.
Are you hardcoding them eg, <img src="http://site.com/image.gif">
Or is it relative, <img src="/image.gif">
Try swapping around what you have with the alternative and see if it works.
=)

Comment: I have my images as something like "images/image.png" so I will try putting in full URLs...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more generic rule that works for more than just 'play'.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?$1=$2 [L]
```

Comment: That does the same thing. As the other answer. 

All my urls inside my page are getting changed to www.site.com/play/whatever